# how to count lines of code in a single file

Tags: php, linux

I'd like to count the number of lines of code in individual files.

sloccount sums up the entire directory.

Is there a program that will return the LOC for a single PHP file?

Comment: Write a shell script to output filename and `wc -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/sloccount.html), just use the `--details` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find /path/of/your/project | xargs wc -l "{}" \;
```